# Multiplying list1 by list2, getting "Warning: match nonexhaustive"

Tags: sml, smlnj

From what I've learned,

```
fun addX (X, []) = []
 |  addX (X, y::ys) = (X + y :: addX(X, ys));
```

works perfectly fine, but when I try to multiply list1 by list2 with this method, it's giving me "Warning: match nonexhaustive", here's my code:

```
fun multList ([], []) = []
 |  multList (x::xs, y::ys) = (x * y :: multList(xs, ys));
```

Which part did I do wrong? any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `x::xs` and `y::ys` matches "non-empty list", your current code is matching the pattern only for:

- `([],[])` ... both list are empty
- `(x::xs,y::ys)` .. both list are non-empty

So you should consider the case "one list is empty, and the another list is non-empty".

The following is the example code which does not show the warning.

```
fun
  multiList ([],[]) = []
  | multiList (X,[]) = X
  | multiList ([],X) = X
  | multiList (x::xs, y::ys) = (x*y ::multiList(xs,ys));
```

This code returns the non-empty one when either of the list is empty.

**Edit:** As @ruakh says in the comment, the following code is better since it seems natural behavior for `multiList`, but I would leave the above code for explanation.

```
fun
  multiList ([],[]) = []
  | multiList (x::xs, y::ys) = (x*y ::multiList(xs,ys))
  | multiList _ = raise Fail "lists of non equal length";
```

Note that `_` is wildcard, so it matches anything when neither `([],[])` nor `(x::xs,y::ys)` matches.

Comment: +1, though I suspect the intended behavior is something actually like `| multiList _ => raise Fail "lists of non-equal length"`.

Comment: thank you sir! I just made `| multiList (X,[]) = raise DifferentLength
  | multiList ([],X) = raise DifferentLength`, which raises a similar exception